# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property error when passing parameter to attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, custom-attributes

In my MVC project, i want to validate an input by other input value. For instance according by following code, it doesn't return validation message if employee is a female and user doesn't choose any military service value but if employee is male, it returns validation message but i am getting this error during the runtime;

*"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property HRManager.Models.Employee.CheckMilitary()"*

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }

    [RequiredByValue(IsRequired = CheckMilitary())]
    public string MilitaryService { get; set; }

    private bool CheckMilitary()
    {
        // If gender is female return false
        return (this.Gender == 0)? false : true;
    }
}

public class RequiredByValue : ValidationAttribute
{
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //todo
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `RequiredByValue` does not do any validation based on `CheckMilitary`. Suggest to read [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) to understand how to create a validation attribute. Or just use one of the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attributes if you don't want to write your own

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are calling a non static property from a static method. You will need to either make the `CheckMilitary` static, or create an instance of `Employee`

seems like you are trying to determine if the gender and thus make the `MilitaryService` field required before you know the 'Employee`

give us an example on how and when you are calling: `HRManager.Models.Employee.CheckMilitary()` and I'll give you proper example on how to fix.

Comment: I have tried this method as static but i am getting this error Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer this time.

Comment: you should be able to then just remove 'this` or it becomes `Employee`